# Script to create XML of directory file list

Tags: xml, perl

Can someone suggest a script to create a xml representation of all the files, alongwith the ones in the sub-directory(on Windows) by file-type. For example, if the current directory name is mypics, then for all jpg's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<images xmlns="http://mydomain.com/images" version="1.0">
  <image>
      <big_url>myassets/pics/funnypics/big_pics/down.jpg</big_url>
  </image>
  <image>      
      <big_url>assets/pics/funnypics/big_pics/spider.jpg</big_url>
  </image>  
</images>
```

then for pdf's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pdfs xmlns="http://mydomain.com/pdf" version="1.0">
  <pdf>
      <big_url>myassets/pics/funnypics/big_pics/down.pdf</big_url>
  </pdf>
  <pdf>      
      <big_url>assets/pics/funnypics/big_pics/spider.pdf</big_url>
  </pdf>  
</pdfs>
```

since, number of filetype is unlimited, i can extend the suggested script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following perl code will do the trick (maybe minus the XML file indentation):

```
package FilesToXml;
use IO;
use File::Find;
use XML::Writer;

use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK);
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(SetRequestedType GenerateXml);

my $group_name = "";
my $file_type = "";
my $ext = "";
my $writer = "";

sub SetRequestedType
{
    $group_name = shift;
    $file_type = shift;
    $ext = shift;
}

sub wanted
{
    if ($File::Find::name =~ /\.$ext$/)
    {
        $writer->startTag($file_type);
        $writer->startTag('big_url');
        $writer->characters($File::Find::name);
        $writer->endTag();
        $writer->endTag();
    }    
}

sub GenerateXml
{
    my $filename = shift;
    my $directory = shift;

    my $output = new IO::File(">$filename");
    $writer = new XML::Writer( OUTPUT => $output );

    $writer->xmlDecl( 'UTF-8' );
    $writer->startTag( $group_name, 'xmlns' => 'http://mydomain.com/'.$group_name, 
                        'version' => '1.0' );
    find(\&wanted, $directory);
    $writer->endTag();  
}

package main;

FilesToXml::SetRequestedType('docs', 'doc', 'docx');
FilesToXml::GenerateXml("output.xml", ".");
```

You basically need to call `SetRequestedType` with the type of the files group, the string describing a single file and the file extension. Then you just need to call `GenerateXml` with the XML output file name and the directory to search under.

It works using ActivePerl on Windows. May need some minor adjustments in other environments.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use XML::Simple;

my $dir = shift || '.';

my %files;
find \&by_extension, $dir;
print XMLout \%files;

sub by_extension {
    return if /^\./;                    # skip dotfiles
    return unless -f;                   # skip non-files
    return unless /\.([^.]+)$/;         # skip if no filename extension
    my $ext = lc $1;                    # ignore case
    $File::Find::name =~ s#^\Q$dir/##;  # trim starting directory name
    push @{$files{$ext . '_files'}{$ext}}, $File::Find::name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing Perl and it's methods for reading directories or handling XML **this is a bit of pseudocode** you could use as a template:

```
strFileExtensionToMap="jpg"
strNodeName="image"
strCollectionName="images"
currentXMLNode=XML.CreateElement(strCollectionName)
StartFolder=Filesystem.GetFolder([however to get folder])
Call RecursiveMapContents(StartFolder)


RecursiveMapContents(folder){
    For each file in folder.Files
    {
        if (file.extension=strFileExtensionToMap)
        xmlFile=XML.CreateElement(strNodeName)
        big_Url=XML.CreateElement("big_url)
        big_url.text=file.path
        xmlFile.AppendChild(big_url)
        currentXMLNode.AppendChild(xmlFile)
    }

    For each subFolder in folder.Folders
    {

        call RecursiveMapContents(subFolder)
    }
}
```

Of course, you could make the XML more generic by using file type as an attribute of a file element:

```
<file type="image"/>
```

You could also map the actual nested directory structure by using

```
<folder name="foldername" path="folderpath"> instead of <images>
```

Then you could include the current folderNode in your call to RecursiveMapContents, so that files and subfolders were nested within it, giving you:

```
<folder name="foldername" path="folderpath">
    <file type="image">
        <big_url>file path</big_url>
    </file>
    <file type="image">
        <big_url>file path</big_url>
    </file>
    <folder name="foldername" path="folderpath">
        <file type="image">
            <big_url>file path</big_url>
        </file>
        <file type="image">
            <big_url>file path</big_url>
        </file>
    </folder>
</folder>
```

I didn't include the namespaces, though I'll admit to being somewhat mystified as to why you'd want separate namespaces for images and pdfs. The point of a namespace is to provide unique naming for a set of elements (so someone else's image element isn't confused with your image element should you want to work with their XML). If you really need a namespace at all then "http://mydomain.com" should be enough for all your element names. A namespace says "this element, which we use shorthand image for is actually called thisnamespace:image". So unless you have two types of image element (one in pdfs, the other in images) and they aren't equivalent the single namespace is enough.

There's also a lot more you could do to make your XML more generic, and possibly less verbose. It's largely up to whoever designs the XML format to specify whether something like a filepath should be an attribute of a file element or a child element (like your big_url), it depends on whether the data needs to be qualified (e.g. filepath="this filepath" type="filesystem|http" should use a child element).

**Sorry it's not a Perl answer, but I hope it helps.**